# Finding variable-length arrays in code

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, variable-length-array

When the size of my input is big enough, segmentation fault sprouts where variable-length arrays are used in a project. I want to remove them all, how to make GCC display every declaration it finds of a variable-length array?

I have tried using `-Wstack-usage=1000` and filtering for the message `warning: stack usage might be unbounded`, but that gives me the function, not the declaration. Is there a better way?

Comment: use option `-std=c89 -pedantic` then `warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array`

Comment: Removing all VLAs sound like overkill. You just need to remove oversized or VLAs with unpredictable size. Maybe you can grep them.

Comment: Well, I don't really consider a VLA where the size is a `static const` variable...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can't do that. Breaks `for(int i = 0;...`.

Comment: I'm mildly alarmed just *how* terrible the code has to be if knowing the function that contains the VLA is not enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was pretty sure I have done that before, and thanks to the comments I found the solution again: use `-Wvla` compiler switch.